# Is it possible to call a servlet from css?

Tags: css, image, servlets, loading

I'm trying to move all the images stored in web application folder to a database. And calling them with a servlet. Is it possible to call a servlet from my css ?? or is there any way to call a remotely stored image file from css??

I tried to call a servlet method from CSS.But couldn't succeed. Is it possible to call a method like this?

background-image: url(servlet/com.abc.servlet.GetImage?name=home&GetImage('abc','123'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Just create an imageservlet like [this example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html#ImageServletServingFromDatabase) here. To the point just obtain the image as `InputStream` from DB by [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(java.lang.String)) and write it to the `OutputStream` of the response as obtained by [`HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) the [usual Java IO way](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/). Don't forget to add the HTTP content type and content length headers. If you omit the content type, the browser don't know what to do with the information. If you omit the content length, it will be sent with chunked transfer encoding, which is a tad less efficient.

As to referencing the servlet in the CSS file, just specify the URL **relative** to the CSS file. This way you don't need to worry about the context path. Determining the relative URL isn't that hard, it works the same way as with accessing local disk filesystem paths in the command console. `cd ../../foo/bar/file.ext` and so on. You've ever learnt that at schools, yes?

OK, assume that the imageservlet is located at `http://example.com/context/image?id=x` and that the CSS file is located at `http://example.com/context/css/globalstyle.css` (thus, the current folder is `css`), then the right relative URL to the imageservlet from inside the CSS file would be:

```
background-image: url('../image?id=123');
```

The `../` goes a step backwards in the directory structure so that you go from the folder `http://example.com/context/css` to `http://example.com/context`. If you still have a hard time in figuring the right relative path, then let us know the **absolute** URL of both the servlet and the CSS file, then we'll extract the correct relative path for you.

Comment: hi..Here is the url's of CSS and servlet.

http://localhost:8080/<contextName>/myStyle.css
  
http://localhost:8080/<contextName>/servlet/com.abc.def.servlet.FileServlet?pictureType=common&pictureName=home.gif

May i know how can i get the path..

Comment: It's in the same parent folder. You can just use `background-image: url('servlet')`.

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed easy if you understand how it fits all in each other.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. As long as the images have urls, you can use it in your css.

For example:

```
background-image:url('/getimage.ashx?id=3');
```

You can even go a step further an reroute their urls - you can even use the same urls you have today, but having your server handle the request and loading files from the database.

Another tip: make sure you set the right headers. You want to use the correct content type, and probably want the images cached properly on the client side.

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the context path from CSS? like request.getContextPath() in jsp.

Comment: It is possible, but that means the CSS is dynamic, and determined at server side - You'll have to configure your server accordingly. Of course, a *CSS* file can be dynamic, just like the images. It doesn't have to be a physical `.css` file.

Comment: hi Kobi..thanks for the quick reply. But i'm bit confused with the use of that in my application. I'm using like this.
background-image: url(/contextName/servlet/com.abc.servlet.FileServlet?pictureType=common&pictureName=home.gif);
But instead of hardcoding of the contextName how can i get it dynamically?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A CSS rule that specifies an image can contain *any* kind of URL that the browser can parse and fetch:

```
body { 
 background-image:
 url(http://www.domain.com/servlets/my_servlet.jsp?argument=value)
}
```